# socket.io-client on server to connect to another server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, server

So I have been working on setting up redundant servers without a single point of failure. I have been looking through a lot of methods and I have settled on using socket.io-client on each server to handle passing messages back and forth between the 2 servers for redundant data. However, no matter what I do, I cannot get the server to connect to the other server. I even scrapped my entire project, started a new one, using extremely simplistic code, and still cannot get the 2 to talk to each other. I have seen multiple questions like this on SO, but none of them have resolved my issue, so I decided to ask and give code samples of my ridiculously simple setup and see if anyone can see why it doesn't connect. I'm telling you, if I didn't already shave my head, I would be ripping my hair out by now. So, here is my simplistic code that doesn't work....

SERVER 1

```
"use strict";
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const ioClient = require('socket.io-client');


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

var client = ioClient('10.0.0.234:3000');
client.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('connected to server');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

SERVER 2 -- exactly the same except for the line...

```
var client = ioClient('10.211.55.7:3000');
```

To point it at the other server. These are both on my local network, and both of them are running at the same time. I even put a client page on each server with a simple connection string, one to the server on that same machine, and one to the server on the other machine, like so...

CLIENT 1 (the 10.0.0.234 machine):

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io("10.0.0.234:3000");
  socket.on('connect', function() {
      console.log('connected to main server');
  })
  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
  });
</script>
```

CLIENT 2 (the 10.211.55.7 machine) - exactly the same except for the connection line which is...

```
var socket = io('10.211.55.7:3000');
```

Both of the clients work, and can connect to their servers. I even switched the IP addresses on the clients so that machine 10.0.0.234's client was using...

```
var socket = io('10.211.55.7:3000');
```

and it connected perfectly. So each client can connect to either server, and it works perfectly, but no matter what I do, I cannot get the server to ever log the 'connected to server' part.

Seriously, am I losing my mind here? IS there some random bug in socket.io-client that won't allow a server to connect to another server, even if it is running the socket.io as a client? I am so very...very... confused, annoyed, fed up, beat up... and all the other adjectives you can think of.
Just in case anyone needs it, here is my package.json file that I am running on both servers...

PACKAGE.JSON...

```
{
  "name": "simple-socket",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "socket server to socket server test",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.10.2",
    "socket.io": "1.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.4.5"
  }
}
```

I know there are other ways of handling redundant backups within node.js,the actual server is much more complex running sticky-session, cluster, redis, socket.io-redis, and others. I just created a simplistic example (actually just kind of used the socket.io chat example as a base) to try to get both servers to talk to each other. No matter what though, it never actually connects to the other server. Yet, somehow both clients can connect to either server, it is just the server will not connect to the other server. Thank you for all the help, and I apologize for the novel here, I am just trying to give all the information I possibly can. Nothing more annoying than trying to help someone who won't give you anything in terms of information, and won't even do some basic research.

Here is a console.log(client); right after the "var client = ioClient('10.0.0.234:3000');

```
Socket {
  io: 
   Manager {
     nsps: { '/': [Circular] },
     subs: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
     opts: 
     { path: '/socket.io',
        hostname: '10.0.0.234',
        secure: false,
        port: '3333' },
     _reconnection: true,
     _reconnectionAttempts: Infinity,
     _reconnectionDelay: 1000,
     _reconnectionDelayMax: 5000,
     _randomizationFactor: 0.5,
     backoff: Backoff { ms: 1000, max: 5000, factor: 2, jitter: 0.5, attempts: 0 },
     _timeout: 20000,
     readyState: 'opening',
     uri: 'http://10.0.0.234:3333',
    connecting: [ [Circular] ],
    lastPing: null,
     encoding: false,
     packetBuffer: [],
     encoder: Encoder {},
     decoder: Decoder { reconstructor: null },
     autoConnect: true,
     engine: 
      Socket {
        secure: false,
        agent: false,
        hostname: '10.0.0.234',
        port: '3333',
        query: {},
        upgrade: true,
        path: '/socket.io/',
        forceJSONP: false,
        jsonp: true,
        forceBase64: false,
        enablesXDR: false,
        timestampParam: 't',
        timestampRequests: undefined,
        transports: [Object],
        readyState: 'opening',
        writeBuffer: [],
        policyPort: 843,
        rememberUpgrade: false,
        binaryType: null,
        onlyBinaryUpgrades: undefined,
        perMessageDeflate: [Object],
        pfx: null,
        key: null,
        passphrase: null,
        cert: null,
        ca: null,
        ciphers: null,
        rejectUnauthorized: null,
        transport: [Object],
       _callbacks: [Object] },
     skipReconnect: false,
     _callbacks: { '$open': [Object], '$packet': [Object], '$close': [Object] } },
  nsp: '/',
  json: [Circular],
  ids: 0,
  acks: {},
  receiveBuffer: [],
  sendBuffer: [],
  connected: false,
  disconnected: true,
  subs: 
   [ { destroy: [Function] },
     { destroy: [Function] },
     { destroy: [Function] } ],
 _callbacks: 
   { '$connecting': [ [Function: onConnecting] ],
     '$connect': [ [Function] ] } }
```

Comment: Are you sure the `socket.io-client` library is installed in your server?

Comment: I can't prove this in looking at the socket.io code, but I think the `ioClient()` constructor wants an actual URL, not just an IP address such as `var client = ioClient('http://10.0.0.234:3000');`

Comment: @jfriend00 I thought the same thing, but on the client side code, it works with the ip. On the client (the html file) it is just io('10.0.0.234:3000'); Are you thinking maybe the socket.io-client has a different connection schema? I haven't tried that, but I could. Also, the socket.io-client is included in teh package.json file and I ran the npm install to make sure all libraries are installed, then I am using the require('socket.io-client'); I can do a console.log(client) or console.log(ioClient) and they both log out a proper socket io object, so it is included. Thank you for the reply

Comment: Rather than all this discussion, why don't you just try it?  Just add the http:// and see if it works.  I've seen that make the difference before.

Comment: @jfriend00 I did, it didn't work. Sorry, I was just trying to respond to you, but yes, I added 'http://' in front and it did not work.

Comment: My last idea without debugging or looking at a network trace is to set up an event handler on the socket for the `error` event to see if it fires and tells you anything about a connect error.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am not sure what exactly happened, last night it wasn't connecting. This morning I decided to try again, and the server that has the 'http://' in front of it, connected to the other server. So that was the issue, but for some reason, whatever it may be, it wasn't connecting last night. Thank you so much for your help. How do I give you credit for this fix? I cant mark your answer as correct, even though that's what it was.